# Access dataset stored on Google Drive from Python local script

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to release space on my laptop by uploading some datasets into Google Drive.

I have a Python script that was loading images and captions from MSCOCO dataset to build a Neural Image Captioning model. How can I keep doing this without downloading that folder on Google Drive into my local? Where should I look for documentation about it?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Pablo

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  If you have a programming question please include your code and describe any issues you are having with your code.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any code and I am not asking for any code. I would like to know if there is any ideas on the case I suggested

Comment: I found this nice post about the issue, for instance: https://towardsdatascience.com/storing-training-data-on-the-cloud-ba815ce20819